# How do I resolve *.internalhost to a given IP address?

Tags: dns

I want all DNS requests that are for *.internalhost to resolve to the same IP address. How is this possible using Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you only need this to happen on one machine, or do you need it to happen for all machines on your local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://daniel.hahler.de/easy-dns-wildcard-setup-for-local-domains-using-dnsmasq

Failing that, set up BIND and create a zone for an "internalhost" TLD with wildcard A record resolution.  Which is probably more work than you're looking for.  (Wildcard resolution from /etc/hosts, which is probably what you *really* want, isn't actually possible.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.